# How we can delete SharePoint Sites/subsites automatically?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, site

I am searching for an option to set expiration policy on site and sub site level on SharePoint 2010.

All i need is to delete unused site/sub site automatically based on expiration criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup auto site deletion feature of SharePoint to delete sites automatically.

http://www.eblogin.com/eblogin/post/2011/03/25/sp-autodeletesite.aspx#.U8NxXfmSxlo

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2011/06/13/mvps-for-sharepoint-2010-practical-sharepoint-governance-for-everyone.aspx

Another approach would be programmatically like :

You can create a Custom timer job to delete Sites/Subsites based on Expiration criteria.

For expiration criteria you can create a "**Site Property**" where you can set the expiration date.

In you custom Timer job you can check the expiration date and delete the site/subsite accordingly.

Comment: Dear Aanchal, the above provided link is explaining how to delete unused site collection.My requirement is to delete sites and subsites.Please suggest if there is any OOB option available on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Hi, you can delete it programmatically according to your business logic.